# How can I get the permalink of a post before it is published?

Tags: permalinks, urls, editor

I'm trying to create a plugin that gives you a push notifications button, through the WordPress editor and I can't find a way to get the permalink of a draft post before its status is set to published.

The predicted permalink already show up in the editor, I just can't find how I can retrieve the same value in my code. `get_post_permalink()` and `get_permalink()` don't work until the post is published.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can get post preview link using `get_preview_post_link()` function to get temporary preview link before the post is published.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_sample_permalink()`

Call `get_sample_permalink( $id )` or if you want to pass your own title or slug into it, the full signature is `get_sample_permalink( $id, $title = null, $name = null)`